# Python: Generating all lists?

Tags: python, list

Is there an easy way to write a generator to generate all lists that are k elements long, where each element ranges from 1 to n?

So if k=3 and n=3, it would generate

```
[1,1,1]
[1,1,2]
[1,1,3]
[1,2,1]
[1,2,2]
[1,2,3]
[1,3,1]
...
[3,3,1]
[3,3,2]
[3,3,3]
```

Answer (score 4):

Using [`itertools.product()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product):

```
import itertools
gen = itertools.product(range(1, k+1), repeat=n)
```

This will generate tuples, if you want lists instead you can use [`itertools.imap()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.imap) or a generator expression, for example:

```
gen = (list(t) for t in itertools.product(range(1, k+1), repeat=n))
```